# Input values into html form using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am having difficulty figuring out where i am going wrong.  Ihave searched the internet for several hours with no luck.  this is my situation.  I am running a mobile device app, i am loading a form (locally) into iframe.  iam then (onload) trying to insert values into my forms textbox.  here is the codes

```
<iframe name="myframe"id="myframe"     
src="file:///C:/Users/denise/Desktop/updateform.html"
width=480px height=400px frameborder=1></iframe>
```

and the javascript function

```
function imLoaded(){
    var ifrm = document.getElementById('myframe');
    var form = doc.getElementById('updateform');
    form.document.getElementById("updateform").user.value = 'hello';
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to update values in the iframe? I believe you need to use `contentDocument` to access things. ex: `document.getElementById('myframe').contentDocument.body`

Comment: `doc`?  `form.document`?  `.user.value`?  This code looks very random...

Comment: @INOH try my answer it work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('myframe');
var innerDoc = (iframe.contentDocument) ? iframe.contentDocument : iframe.contentWindow.document;
alert(innerDoc.getElementById("updateform").innerHTML);
alert(innerDoc.getElementById("updateform")["user"].value);
```

you can use `innerDoc` with `getElementById` to get any element of id

Hope this will help you.

Comment: here is my form that is loaded into my iframe code  `<html> 
<form id="updateform" method="post" name="update" action="update.php" /> 
Name:   
 <input type="text" name="user"/>   
Password:   
<input type="text" name="userpassword" /> 
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="update" /> 
</form>   
</html>`

Comment: @INOH you created a function `imLoaded` just comment all lines inside this function and paste this on that page where you have added this iframe(`myframe` using <iframe ...</iframe>) there you have to write this script

Comment: @INOH to get value of user try this `alert(innerDoc.getElementById("updateform")["user"].value);` also updated my answer, try now

Comment: how do i set that value to the form i have loaded into my iframe

Comment: @INOH try like this `innerDoc.getElementById("updateform")["user"].value = "Test Data";`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function imLoaded() {
    $('iframe[name=myframe]').contents().find('#updateform').user.value = 'hello'
});
```

Tell me if it works and I'll update the answer with more informations.

Comment: that's because you have not include js in your other html file I believe. Or do you?  Check if jquery is properly loaded on both files (iframe and index)

Comment: OP didn't request jQuery. @INOH, the reason why there's an error, is because the answer requires jQuery. There is nothing wrong on your side.